# Firefox Add-on SDK: create Panel right below selected text, even with zoom and sidebars

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, getboundingclientrect

I'm using the Firefox Add-on SDK to create a Panel when the user selects text in a page. The panel should always appear below and to the right of the selected text, so I use the following (in a content script) to get its position:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
var position = {left: rect.right, top: rect.bottom}
...
```

This position is sent in an event and used to position the panel. This works well, but **there are two issues:**

- page zoom level
- browser sidebars

The position returned by getBoundingClientRect (and even getClientRects) does not account for these, so **the panel has an offset from the right position** if a sidebar is open (left sidebars make the panel move to the left relative to the text) or zoom is applied.

Is there any way to **always** calculate the real position where the panel should be shown? (Maybe using the sdk/window/utils module?)